# Laravel 9- Model Class not found

Tags: laravel

**Class "App\Post" not found**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
 
    public function index(): Response
    {
    
        return view('posts.index',[
            'Posts'=>Post::all()
        ]);
    }

}
```

the code in PostController.php
When starting to work with models I got the following error : Class "App\Post" not found

Comment: Are you sure it is not supposed to be `use App\Models\Post;` ? Look at your project directory structure

Comment: Adding to jef's comment, models created by `make:model` on Laravel 8+ are under `app/Models` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello **ilyas zagaouch**,

To make a model in Laravel 9 we will use the `make:model` Artisan command followed by the Model name.

**Syntax:**
`php artisan make:model [ModelName]`

**Example:**
`php artisan make:model Post`

And this is the code you are going to change with.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(): Response
    {   
        return view('posts.index',[
            'Posts' => Post::all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i make this change , and now i have this error : App\Http\Controllers\PostController::index(): Return value must be of type Illuminate\Http\Response, Illuminate\View\View returned

Comment: @ilyaszagaouch Laravel 10 "[introduces argument and return types to all application skeleton methods, as well as all stub files used to generate classes throughout the framework](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/releases#laravel-10)" as you can see in the [documentation for controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#basic-controllers). Return Types are relatively new in Laravel but are covered by the documentation and over at [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-10/episodes/10), which should give you a good starting point for learning Laravel.

Comment: If you want to return the view. then you have to import 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

and change it in method,
public function index(): View